# Unable to read event Content from a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to HTML and Javascript. I was working on creating a basic login screen.

[image]

As I am trying to print the value of the email and the password in the console, I get nothing. Can someone help me out?

```js
document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  console.log(email, password);
});
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
  <h2 class="heading-secondary ma-bt-lg">Log into your account</h2>
  <form class="form"></form>
  <div class="form__group">
    <label class="form__label" for="email">Email address</label
        ><input
          class="form__input"
          id="email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="you@example.com"
          required=""
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form__group ma-bt-md">
        <label class="form__label" for="password">Password</label
        ><input
          class="form__input"
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="••••••••"
          required=""
          minlength="8"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="form__group">
        <button class="btn btn--green">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <script src="/js/login.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Does your form have a closing `</form>` tag? Yes it does. Your code is like`<form class="form"></form>` You close it so there are ZERO elements inside of the form. The input elements and submit button are not children of it so they will not submit that form tag. So move the `</form>` after all your elements.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `<form class="form"></form>` is empty, you should put the inputs inside it.

```html
<div class="login-form">
    <h2 class="heading-secondary ma-bt-lg">Log into your account</h2>
    <form class="form">
        <div class="form__group"><label class="form__label" for="email">Email address</label><input class="form__input" id="email" type="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required="" /></div>
        <div class="form__group ma-bt-md"><label class="form__label" for="password">Password</label><input class="form__input" id="password" type="password" placeholder="••••••••" required="" minlength="8" /></div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <button class="btn btn--green">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```